# Intel OpenCL SDK - where are the header files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencl

I'm trying to use OpenCL on my ultrabook with Iris graphics, therefore I've installed the Intel OpenCL SDK 2013 (the one from here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk).

Trying to do something with it, however I fail to find the directory where the header file (CL/cl.h) is stored... there's no include subdirectory in the install location, and also no headers in the Visual Studio / SDK folders... a search for cl.h on my C: drive also didn't give any results.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to install anything else to get the headers?

I've only used the AMD OpenCL SDK before, there the headers are neatly located in an include subdirectory of the installation folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the installer didn't run through properly. The last page looked inconspicous and had a nice Finish button, but only the Runtime got installed, but not the Application SDK. The Installer says something like "Installation ended prematurely because of an error" (no more specific information as to what error it was that had occured).

The reason is that the Installer doesn't seem to like my Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition.

Deactivating the "Visual Studio (2010) integration" made the installation be successful, and made the includes turn up.

Comment: By the way you can always download the [`cl.h` header directly from Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.h), but of course an incomplete installation may hide other issues.

Comment: I had to do the same but with Visual C++ 2012 Express Edition. At this point I'm assuming it doesn't integrate with any Express Edition of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it's under:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\<version>\include\CL\cl.h
```

Are you sure the installation was completed successfully? Do you have a `bin` folder under the `OpenCL SDK` folder?

Comment: I do have the OpenCL SDK folder, but it only contains a bin and an uninstall folder, and a readme.txt - will try to reinstall

Comment: you are right about the installation completion - it says "ended prematurely" (although the dialog does look like it went successful). will have to check what causes this problem... any ideas? I've seen no logfile, an

Comment: It seems that the SDK doesn't work with my Express Edition, I now deactivated the VS integration and the installation was successful

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (+1). Since it was only a pointer in the correct direction, I will write a separate answer for that, though!

Comment: @nyarlathotep glad I could help! (and glad to see people who know how to use this site properly, will +1 your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the current version of the SDK, it is at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\system_studio_2020\OpenCL\sdk\include
```

As installed by `intel_sdk_for_opencl_applications_2020.3.494.zip` downloaded from https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/opencl-sdk.html